# iPhone: Image gets inverted

Tags: iphone, image, light

I'm having a problem with my image on my iPhone app.

When I run my app on my simulator, everything looks good and there's no problem.

But now I've installed the app on my device with [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com) and the image seems to be inverted. Normally it's a very bright image, and now it's all dark, and some parts are extremely light.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Thanks

Tjeu

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think there must be some problem with the orientation. 
Try with face up and face down orientation.